# How to implement a bi-directional zero-to-one association with JPA using left join strategy?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, left-join, one-to-one

I'd like to implement a bi-directional zero-to-one association with JPA. For the moment, I use the following snippet :

```
@Entity
class A {
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private B a;
...
}


@Entity
class B {
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private A a;
...
}
```

The problem is that when I try to load my entity A, the fetch type strategy used to load entity B is systematically a 'FetchType.SELECT', i.e; for each entity A found, a select statement is completed in order to get the associated entity B. I tried to deal with this problem using the @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) hibernate annotation (see below), but it doesn't work.

```
@Entity
class A {
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

    // ineffective hibernate annotation
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private B a;
...
}
```

Comment: Do you use EntityManager or hibernate's Session? Maybe this could be an issue?

Comment: Also try specifying in B entity @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true, **mappedBy="a"**)? Maybe it is an issue because of both being PKJoinColumn?

Comment: Thanks JMelnik. I'm using EntityManager. For the moment, my problem is resolved using a namedquery from A with a left join fetch on B + using FetchType.LAZY instead of FetchType.EAGER. But it's a workaround.